# Autofill textfield in WPCF7(contact form 7 plugin) using dynamic value

Tags: wordpress

I have a wpcf7 form on my wordpress site and I want to auto-fill a text field using a dynamic value in URL. Can anyone point me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and this is how I solved it

1) Install http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-modules/

2) Create a hidden form item with an id (fooBar ie).

3) Then in your function.php file

```
add_filter('wpcf7_hidden_field_value_fooBar', 'wpcf7_hidden_field_add_query_fooBar');
function wpcf7_hidden_field_add_query_fooBar($value = '') {
    if(isset($_GET['YourGetParamHere'])) {
        return $_GET['YourGetParamHere'];
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to auto fill the loggedin user details in contact form 7

Comment: I suppose it's too late : http://contactform7.com/setting-default-values-to-the-logged-in-user/